# Why do I have to use :classes:. notation after a jar in -classpath argument?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I'm reading some book on advanced Java, and I'm instructed to compile `.java` file with the following command:

```
javac -d classes -classpath c:\somepath\somejar.jar;classes:.
```

I wonder:

1. Are `:.` these symbols represent one argument or `:` and `.` separately are different arguments after the `classes` keyword? what do they stand for?
2. Why do we need to provide `classes:.` at all after `somejar.jar`? as all of these combinations:
   `javac -d classes -classpath c:\somepath\somejar.jar;classes:.`
   `javac -d classes -classpath c:\somepath\somejar.jar;classes:`
   `javac -d classes -classpath c:\somepath\somejar.jar;classes`
   `javac -d classes -classpath c:\somepath\somejar.jar;`

work absolutely same. They produce precisely same `.class` files (226 bytes each) and when I deploy them within Web container, they work identically.

So what's the point in those symbols? how above four `javac ..` commands differ? Anyone who can explain this clearly, please?

Comment: best would be to ask the book author. THe classpath is used for the compiler to know where to search for already compiled classes used by the file(s) being compiled. E.g. if you have already compiled one file that is used by a second class, when compiling that second class the compiler knows where to search for the first. Same is used when executing code, the classpath tells where to find the class files. The directories are not stored in the classfiles.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos. Yeah, you're right, I know this and it's clear to me. My question is about notation.. however, important clue which you mention (others may find this useful) is that, yeah, exactly: "compiler looks for ALREADY COMPILED files, and not for the source files. I'm having quite a strange problem.. when I do this shell compilation, for some reason, List is not recognized anymore. Does -classpath argument override other default jar files? so that java.util package gets out of context?

Comment: Sorry, I remember I typed java-compiler. Most likely, some auto-suggested tag sneaked in.. I know what is compiler construction.

Comment: The only tags resembling that are [tag:Java-compiler-api] and [tag:javacompiler], and they aren't relevant either. Nor is [tag:jar].

Comment: you know that? then I didn't understand the question... and it changed a lot now! `:` (or `;` for windows) is the separator; `.` is the actual working directory, You only need folder `classes` if there are some class files there that are not already part of the other parts (like jar file). Mostly if you are compiling more than one file, which obviously is not (updated) in the JAR file.[PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) or [setting the classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : the '.' is not 'as far as I know' for me - it is the standard relative pathing for the current directory and is commonly used when providing paths as arguments. The 'as far as I know' point for me is why the author of the book you are reading decided to use both the ';' and ':' delimiters in the given example.

Comment: I say how it is, so I'm not sure whether it's a mismatch or match, for this probably you should see the book, and the book isn't about this. This was solely my question, because I didn't understand something. P. S. I wish Stackoverflow had the community where you guys don't scold at people remonstrating with your super powers, but just share the knowledge if you have appropriate.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : I am sorry you felt that you are being scolded here. This was never my intention, and I agree with you that some SO users are somewhat harsh in their replies. I tried to share my knowledge and the results of a couple of hours of online research I invested in answering this IMHO interesting question. Take care buddy, and keep on asking questions on SO.

Comment: @RannLifshitz, cheers, mate. Yes, there are lots of unreasonably harsh and impolite people.. so thank you for your acclaim.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : Sure thing. Like I said - keep on asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `;` and `:`delimiters used in the classpath value are used in order to delimit multiple folders as the values of the classpath.

`;` is used for delimiting folders under the Windows OS.

`:` is used for delimiting folders under *nix OSs.

The `-d classes` argument in conjunction with `classes:.` implies that the compiled `.class` files will be placed in the classes folder instead of the standard placement based on the package hierarchy.

Therefore, the inclusion of classes as an additional argument of the classpath allows the referencing of previously compiled class files when compiling new java classes. The `.` is a classpath reference to the directory from which the `javac` command has been executed - the current working directory.

The only issue here is the mixing of the two delimiter types. Why this is done - I do not know.

References:

- [How to specify multiple class search directories in the classpath option of javac](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-specify-multiple-class-search-directories-in-the-classpath-option-of-javac/66)
- [Oracle documentation on classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)
- [Oracle documentation on javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: Thank you, Rann! However, few clarifications:
1. Multiple folders? or multiple .jar files? when I, for instance, enlist several jars as the values of -classpath, I have a thought, that I'm specifying them by delimiting them accordingly (either ; or : depending on OS); or I got it wrong? you say, that delimiter is used to delimit between folders? that means in my example only classes folder will be included?
2. what about the final period? why we need that?
3. -d classes works perfect even if you don't provide any classpath.. it is just destination of compiled files, I assume (?)

Comment: I think -d classes and -classpath's value :classes. doesn't have anything in common. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : 

1.Multiple folders, which can contain jars and/or .class files. You can also specify specific files (jars). You must use a delimiter between the folders and files. 2. The final period, as far as I know, is a referencing to the folder from which the javac command has been executed from. 3. (-d) specifies the destination of the compiled source files. as for the relation between the -d classes and the classpath classes - I do think they are related. The idea is to provide compiled class files to the classpath.

Comment: so I saw you've edited question and changed both ";classes" and ";classes:" with ";classes:.". I thought these symbols (colon, and dot) were representing separate ideas. Do you want to tell me that they're part of one parameter/argument which is "classes:." ? (well, in that case ; does not belongs to classes:., it's just for delimiting one argument from another)

Comment: Maybe you can review my question. I'm asking something different rather than what is ";" and ":"

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : Your first comment - ':.' is a delimiter + a referencing to the working directory provided to the classpath.'classes' can be provided as a standalone directory, '.' is just another folder, and ':' delimits between the two. Carlos Heuberger's last comment is a confirmation of the answer I provided - it is basically a summery of the answer.